# Dell XPS 8700 dual monitor configuration

Tags: multiple-monitors

Can I connect a VGA monitor with an AMD Radeon HD 4350 video card and and Dell U2414H monitor to a Dell XPS 8700? And how?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to attach a VGA to the Radeon HD4350 card as the card should have a blue VGA port on the back of it. As for the U2414H Monitor, your XPS 8700 should have a HDMI port at the back of it, and the monitor should have the port also, so all you would need to do is attach the the U2414H to the computer by a HDMI cable, and attach the VGA monitor straight to the Radeon 4350 VGA port using a VGA cable. Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually what I want is to attach the VGA monitor to the XPS 8700 along with the HDMI monitor so I can use both monitors together.

Comment: If the machine has  VGA port on the back then it's possible to attach it directly to the XPS8700. However if it doesn't then I suggest attaching the VGA to the HD4350. If you want to attach the U2414H monitor to the card as well to make it easier, then you can always attach a DVI to HDMI adapter. Either way you can make both displays work with the method I mentioned above. Attach the U2414H to the XPS8700 and VGA to HD 4350 video card. But if the XPS 8700 does have a VGA port on the back then you just attach both and both screens will work.